# How to reset Drupal's content cache / deleted content?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm working with Drupal 7.44. I created some content, but then deleted those articles. However, when I go to add new content, Drupal still recognizes the title of my articles that I deleted (as I'm typing it appears as an autocomplete below the field). I'm not sure if this is still completely stored in the database or if it's just cached somewhere. How do I go about deleting this (preferably without completely having to re-install everything)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Administration -> Configuration -> Development -> Performance
and "Clear all caches" shouldn't work?

Comment: Hi, just tried this, but the content is still there. Wondering if these are still actually written to the database (?).

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a browser cache issue. Using a different browser or clearing the browser's cache did it.